# A better way to count the number of requests from an IP address within 5 minutes to an application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

I'm trying to use [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to set a rate limit on an application load balancer.

One thing that I feel difficult is to count the number of requests sent from each IP address.

Currently, the way I count this number is to use excel to analyze the [access log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) of the load balancer.

This is really inconvenient because the time period of a log file (`123456789123_elasticloadbalancing_<my_region>_app.awseb-AWSEB-KOAJA32RNYD8.3doo93xxx07e93c7_20200210T0010Z_13.232.79.235_3o9wv54o.log.gz`) is only 5 minutes.

To analyze a 24 hour time period, I have to download and extract `24 * 60 / 5 = 288` log files stored in an S3 bucket.

Is it possible to get the number of requests for each IP address within 5 minutes directly from AWS WAF?

Comment: If you want to count exactly the number of request per IP, I suggest using python script to read content of the logs files to count it (require basic python skill). I think you just set the limit base on your estimation, and monitor it and maintain the number later

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at S3 Select (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html)? It might provide a solution here.